# Are there any reasons why it is particularly difficult to implement the multi-output regression function for the boosting based models?

Tags: python

I"m looking for a boosting based models(ADABOOST, XGBOOST, LGB) that support multi-output regression just like that of a Scikit Learn's RandomforestRegressor. But I can't find any.

I'm just curious. Is there a special reason? For example, gradient-based boosting models require more memory, something like that?